# pandas: detect and print outliers in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outliers

I am trying to identify and print the rows of a dataframe containing outliers.
Just as an experiment, I am considering outliers all values under the column 'xy' between 6 and 10 that correspond to category 'C' under column 'x'. I am not sure why, my code prints an empty output.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=[['A', 1,2 ,5],
        ['B', 5,5,6],
        ['C', 4,6,7]
        ,['A', 6,5,4],
        ['B',9,9,3],
        ['C', 7,9,1]
        ,['A', 2,3,1],
        ['B', 5,1,2],
        ['C',2,10,9]
        ,['B', 8,2,8],
        ['B', 5,4,3],
        ['C', 8,5 ,3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x','y','z','xy'])
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['xy']) 
outliers= (df['xy'].between(6,10,inclusive=False)  & df['x']=='C')
outliers_location=(df[outliers].index.values.tolist())

print(outliers_location) # should not print an empty list
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the second condition into `()` otherwise it is parsed incorrectly. Without it, it tries to compare `df['xy'].between(6,10,inclusive=False)  & df['x']` to `C`

```
>>> outliers= (df['xy'].between(6,10,inclusive=False)  & (df['x']=='C'))
>>> outliers_location=(df[outliers].index.values.tolist())
>>> print(outliers_location)
[2, 8]
```